# How to make toast in Visual Studio Cordova App?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am working on VS2013 Cordova App . I want to make toast in my app as it in native android  . I searched in plugins in config.xml and I didn't find the toast plugin . please advice .

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called: Cordova Push Notifications. This plugin implements toast noticiations in your cordova app. Here is a sample how to implement this in Android and other platform as tequested:

https://github.com/appfeel/cordova-push-notifications

Hope this helps.

Comment: I add it into my project , What can I add in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

I used [Eddy Verbruggens toast plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-toast) in one of my projects. It's pretty easy to use: Just add it to your project and call it something like

```
window.plugins.toast.show('Your toasts text goes here', 'long', 'bottom');
```

---

Edit: You can add the plugin as any other plugin using Visual Studio: Double click on your config.xml -> Plugins -> Custom. Then choose Git and copy the URL to the Git-Repo in the blue area, press the button with the arrow next to it. In the end you have to click the Add button on the right (marked red) to add the plugin to your project.

[image: Adding a custom plugin in VS]

If there is a problem with adding a plugin in Visual Studio try using the command line like so `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-toast` where  cordova-plugin-x-toast is the name of the plugin to install.

---

Edit: I made a [repo](https://github.com/swifmaneum/CordovaToastDemo) for the sake of demonstration. It's basically the Visual Studio Cordova App template with a button showing a toast. Just check it out and see what I did there. The [index.js](https://github.com/swifmaneum/CordovaToastDemo/blob/master/CordovaToastDemo/www/scripts/index.js) might be most interesting. Make sure to test it on an actual device or emulator, **Ripple Simulator does not support this plugin**.

Comment: I want to use VS plugins , is there any way to use vs plugins ? thanx

Comment: Sure double click on your config.xml -> plugins -> custom, choose Git and paste the URL of the repository: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin.git , I'll add a picture to the answer...

Comment: I have done this and it has been add successfully . now i have add "window.plugins.toast.show('Your toasts text goes here', 'long', 'bottom');"    but it didn't worked  with me .